# How to know if a value is inside a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I'm still learning how to use. I have the follow dictionary:

```
dic = {'0': {'text': 'a', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '4'}, '1': {'text': 'b', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '3'}, '2': {'text': 'c', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '1'}, '3': {'text': 'd', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '2'}, '4': {'text': 'e', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '5'}}
```

Now, I'm trying to know if the text, for example, 'a' is a value of any of those nested dictionaries (I know there is a value() function which returns the values of the dictionaries, but in this case it will only return the values of the first dictionary, won't it? Like 0,1,2,3,4)

I tried

```
for i in range(len(dic)):
  if text in dic[i].values():
    print("Yes")
  else:
    print("No")
```

But this gives me a KeyError with value '0'. I have searched for similar questions, but haven't found any which I can use to solve my problem. Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for i in range(len(dic))` will iterate through integers up to the number of keys in your dictionary, which here, might work. But, what you actually want is `for k in dic`, which will iterate through the keys.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `any`:

```
dic = {'0': {'text': 'a', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '4'}, '1': {'text': 'b', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '3'}, '2': {'text': 'c', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '1'}, '3': {'text': 'd', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '2'}, '4': {'text': 'e', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '5'}}
result = any('a' in d.values() for d in dic.values())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any` with a generator comprehension, [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51104686/9209546) by @Ajax1234.

Or, if you do this repeatedly, you can calculate a `set` of values and check for membership with O(1) complexity. `itertool.chain` is a useful tool to combine nested values:

```
from itertools import chain

values = set(chain.from_iterable(i.values() for i in dic.values()))

res = 'a' in values  # True
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting first from what you have tried, you could indeed:

- Use a `for` loop to iterate over the values of `dic`, that are dictionaries too.
- Check inside each dictionary if the value of the key `'text'` equals `'a'`.
- If yes, then print `'Yes'` and stop the loop.
- If the loop ends without any match, then print `'No'`.

Let's do it with a beautiful `for/else` statement:

```
for d in dic.values():
    if d['text'] == 'a':
        print("Yes")
        break
else:
    print("No")
```

To go further, you could also:

- use comprehension to perform the `for` loop and the `==` operation in a smarter Python way,
- and use `any` to replace the `if` and `break` statements by a smarter Python built-in function.

This shorter code will in fact do exactly the same things as previous one, in a really pythonic way:

```
if any(d['text'] == 'a' for d in dic.values()):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that the string you are looking for will no be in key names, then another simple solution is converting whole dict to str and searching for string

```
if 'a' in str(dic):
    print("a is there")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the dictionary as a list. You cannot index into a dictionary, like this:

```
dic[0]
```

But you can get the value from a given key, like so:

```
dic["0"] # yields {'text': 'a', 'lang': 'es', 'rating': '4'}
```

As such, modify your for loop as follows:

```
for i in dic:
    ...
```